# ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant GenresController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, integration-testing, rails-api

Currently following Code School's [*Soup to Bits: Surviving APIs with Rails*](https://www.codeschool.com/screencasts/soup-to-bits-surviving-apis-with-rails) tutorial.

While implementing a new `Genre` model, I first got the following error:

```
11:56:18 - INFO - Running: test/integration/listing_genres_test.rb
Started

ERROR["test_lists_genres", ListingGenresTest, 2015-07-26 18:26:25 -0700]
 test_lists_genres#ListingGenresTest (1437960385.93s)
ActionController::RoutingError:         ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/genres"
            test/integration/listing_genres_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:ListingGenresTest>'
        test/integration/listing_genres_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:ListingGenresTest>'

  1/1: [===================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.06051s
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

So, I created `resources :genres` in the `config/routes.rb` file to fix it, which resulted in a new error:

```
11:59:45 - INFO - Running: all tests
Started

ERROR["test_lists_genres", ListingGenresTest, 2015-07-26 18:26:26 -0700]
 test_lists_genres#ListingGenresTest (1437960386.04s)
ActionController::RoutingError:         ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant GenresController
            test/integration/listing_genres_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:ListingGenresTest>'
        test/integration/listing_genres_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:ListingGenresTest>'

  8/8: [===================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.23204s
8 tests, 23 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

In the tutorial, however, the tests pass.

Here is the `listing_genres_test.rb` file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ListingGenresTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test 'lists genres' do
    get '/genres'

    assert_equal 200, response.status
    assert_equal Mime::json, response.content_type
  end
end
```

And here is the `genres_controller.rb` file:

```
class GenresController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: Genre.all, status: 200
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One thing, GenresController should have a matching plural filename genres_controller.rb unless that's just a typo?

Comment: Thanks. That was just a typo, indeed. I updated the question to prevent further confusion.

Comment: If you start your rails server, can you access http://localhost:3000/genres? and if not, is your genres_controller.rb in app/controllers directory?

Comment: Ok, I must be really tired... you were kind of right in the first place, there was a problem with my controller name. It was not a singular/plural issue though: I must have mistyped the file name, as it was `genres.controller.rb` when I when to check it out in the `controllers` folder. If you want to suggest to check controller's name in an answer, I will be happy to approve it, since it was actually the root cause of the problem. My mistake. And thanks a lot for your time and your help.